# How to use less memory splitting file with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with 36GB that is a nginx log that is compressed using gzip.
I want to split this file in smaller files, so I can use these small files as input in another script that I've made without running out of memory.
The first column of this file has the IP address and all requests from a specific IP address should be in the same file after splitted.

What I currently have to achieve what I need is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$1
NUM_FILES=$(($2))
PREFIX=$3

unpigz -c  $FILENAME | awk -v NUM_FILES=$NUM_FILES -v PREFIX=$PREFIX \
'! ($1 in out) {out[$1] = (idx++ %NUM_FILES) } '\
'{ outfile= PREFIX"." out[$1] ".txt"; print | ("pigz >" outfile) ; next} '
```

Although everything works as expected, it's using too much memory and I only have 16GB available in my computer, so I'm not able to split it for files bigger than x GBs.

I want to know if it's possible to waste less memory in this situation somehow.

Comment: why are you even trying to split a file with awk? there is a tool called `split` that does exactly what the name implies (split files into pieces). have you tried that instead?

Comment: @derbender the source file is sorted by datetime, not by IP, and I need that all requests from an IP be in the same file.

Comment: Neither `split` nor `csplit` will distribute that large file's contents by the IP in $1. I don't see anything clogging up memory in your approach except maybe the piping into `pigz` which will keep umpteen pipes and processes open if there are many different IPs. Why not print to simple regular files and run `pigz` on those after `awk` has finished?

Comment: `sort` by IP, then?

Comment: I dont have nginx so i have no own log to play around with can you post a small excerpt of a log to play around with? possibly with multiple ip addresses in so it is easy to test that it does in fact split by ip

Comment: @RudiC The file size is 36GB compressed, it's impossible to remove this pigz because I won't have enough space

Comment: (a) There is no purpose in using unpigz -c. The man page says "Decompression can't be parallelized". The big file is specified to be gzip-compatible, so just use gunzip. The separate outputs are small -- no need for the pigz overhead on every one of those, either. (b) There is no logical connection between 36GB file (probably 200GB uncompressed) and 16GB RAM. The only RAM use is the array of output filenames, and the overhead of an open file per IP address. So:: how many distinct IP addresses do you have? And do you have 200+GB disk space free temporarily?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I did some tests and unpigz -c is faster than gunzip, I think it uses threads to [optimize something](https://github.com/madler/pigz/issues/36#issuecomment-249041503), anyway I don't think it's relevant here. The separate output is not small, it will be the size of input descompressed that is 480GB. `gunzip -c 0620.gz | wc --bytes` has the following result: `516455869186`. I don't know about the number of IP addresses

Comment: It may be somewhat faster, but that is at the expense of as many threads as it chooses to run (the compression is chunked in 128KB slices). That uses memory for the processes, and disc cache, and your main question is "How can I do this with less memory". Also, you are then stuffing the data into a single pipe (currently running awk). So your multithreaded supersmart unpigz is spending 80% of its time waiting for data to go down that first pipe, and making all that memory unusable for the entire runtime.

Comment: In addition, you are splitting th 480GB unpacked data into as many streams as you have IP addresses. Suppose you have 48,000 distinct IP addresses. You are then running 48,000 distinct pipes each running a subshell and a pigz on its own 10MB data set. Running 96,000 processes may just be why your machine clags up, maybe? Thats why I was curious about the number of distinct IPs.

Comment: I found some work I did on a very similar problem a couple of years back on IT ToolBox. I found my emails, the code should be around somewhere. My old Laptop got a 2000 times speedup against the original attempt, and split a million rows across 25000 keys in around 20 secs, using half a GB RAM.

Comment: It's about 400,000 IP adresses. You're right about the unpigz, I'll remove it. Thank you for the help. If you find the code please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have been chasing unicorns and rainbows this week. I have timed three strategies. For all timings, I am extrapolating my 20 million rows to your (estimated) 8 billion rows, but timed for my Laptop and HDD. I compressed my test file for timing purposes, but only had gunzip to unpack it.

**(A) Reading a memory (maybe 10GB) full of rows**, and then streaming them out to files (one file at a time). I was under the misapprehension the requirement was to put each IP into a different file. That involves appending and closing 400K files for about each 10GB of data. My runtime for that would be **120 hours**. That also lands you with the need to manage 400,000 files. None of that is good.

**(B) Making a multipass on the 36GB file (360GB unpacked)**. I was at this point under the misapprehension you did not have space for the whole 500GB of the data when separated out.

As it happens, multiple passes are not that expensive. The idea is to group IPs in an index. So you might make 8 passes, write 100 files in each pass, and have 500 IPs in each file, and about 10 million rows per file, and 800 files. Runtime should be around **33 hours**, the multipass being much faster than multiple file appends. There are also other advantages:

.. You can do with less disk space, because you can compress all the files in one group before starting the next.

.. You can schedule each group e.g. to run overnight when system demand might be low.

.. You have restart points per group, in case of failures.

.. The group files are an index to locate the file containing particular IPs.

**(C) As you say you have sufficient disk to have one unpacked copy of everything, your original script is perfectly good**, with three minor revisions.

.. You can't afford to compress each output file in a process, but you can just write all the files and compress them later, perhaps with careful use of GNU parallel.

.. I was seeing a sweet spot in my timings in the number of awk output files. Empirically, 100 output files is faster (for the same total data volume) than either 80 or 120. It may be inadvisable to attempt much more than a 100-way split, so you may end up with 100 files, each containing around 80 million rows and 4000 IPs.

.. It is cleaner to compose the filename for each IP once, rather than for each write.

My estimate for this method is **24 hours**.

So your original now looks like:

```
time gunzip -c ../trial.data.gz | awk '
! ($1 in X) { X[$1] = sprintf ("Prefix_%.4d.dat", q++ % 100); }
{ print > X[$1]; }'
```

Comment: Code for option (B) is tested and available, should you wish it. Around 110 lines, so probably better on PasteBin.

Comment: thank you for the additional information and the advice. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach for getting such tasks done is to split the work load, doing the whole work in two steps (your harddisk is going to love that).

Instead of creating one file (and one pipeline with one compressor process in memory) for each IP address you create one file for e.g. each value in the last IP octet:

```
unpigz -c  $FILENAME | awk -v NUM_FILES=$NUM_FILES -v PREFIX=$PREFIX \
'{ last_octet=$0; sub("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.","",last_octet); }; '\
! (last_octet in out) {out[last_octet] = 1 } '\
'{ outfile= PREFIX"." last_octet ".txt"; print | ("pigz >" outfile) ; next} '
```

And after that you let your code run over each of those files. Probably makes sense to put some thought in it how you can keep the resulting files in memory until they reach a certain size if this is not stored on SSDs.

Comment: For the sake of argument, suppose that the 400,000 IP addresses in the data are evenly distributed over the octets, as (25).(25).(25).(25). Your first run takes 1 file and makes 25. Second time through, you run 25 processes and make 625 files. Third time, 625 processes and make 15625 files. Fourth time, 15625 processes and make the 400,000 files. Total processes > 16000, and the whole data volume all got decompressed, read, written and recompressed 4 times. Possible to parallel most of it, but hard to administer properly.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant My math was a little different. The addresses will be about evenly distributed among the last octet, probably within the third, too, but certainly not in the first and probably not in the second. You were talking about 48,000 IP addresses before. That would be two rounds. 256 files in the first round and then one more round for each of those 256 files.

Comment: That was a "suppose" to argue the case that there were a silly number of processes being invoked. The OP then revealed there are 400,000 IPs. However, I revisited the original OP script, and realised he is using a smaller number of files anyway, so we still don't know what split factor is actually required.

Answer (score 0):

I have a GNU/awk script to do this. However, there are a bunch of issues with performance, disk space and file management that it might be worth considering at this point.

**Design Notes -- Origins.**

I found my code, and thought it would be helpful to test it again. This was originally a simple forum post: given a file with a US State code in a known column, how to separate it into distinct files without knowing which states were present. Simple: the data tells you as it arrives. I just opened a new file for each new state. So 60+ files was no problem (it included US overseas territories).

I wondered how far GNU/awk would go with that. It supports an unlimited number of output files, but when it reaches the ulimit (1024) it fakes that by closing and reopening. You can increase ulimit, but probably not to 400,000. For a large number of files and random input sequence, that approximates to a file open/close per line -- a pathological case. I ran using a different key field (with 25K distinct values), and tried a number of designs using multi-pass, cascade and trees of processes, before I found a solution that was faster and simpler.

The basic solution is to get as many rows as you can, and stuff them into a 2-D array. Then flush them, ordered by file and original sequence. This avoids fragmentation on disk, and only needs a single output file open at once.

**Test Data.**

I looked at the nginx website for log formats, and (unless you have configured every optional field) I assume you have an IP address, followed by maybe 60 characters of text. So I stitched together 20 million lines of data (1.5 GB):

.. 400,000 IP addresses expanded and randomised from: {10..29}.{30..39}.{80..129}.{110..149}

.. 490,306 text lines pulled from the Harvard CS50 test pack, excluding lines not between 40 to 90 chars.

Both those were replicated to 20M rows, and then joined.

**Evaluation.**

Performance -- measured on a Laptop, 4GB, HDD.

My 20M rows (1.5GB) take 15 minutes (from plain text without decompression). I see no reason for performance not to be O(n), so your 480GB raw data would take around 80 hours. Your server is probably rather faster than my Samsung RV515.

**Memory**

I used 6 million rows for my memory array, plus the incremental array of known IPs and filenames. That used about 2.7GB of my 4MB -- more than that caused excessive swap and REISUB.

**Output Files**

Using more space should be beneficial. Each flush only averages 15 rows per output file append (6M rows / 400K keys). Using 10 times the memory would avoid 90% of the file management.

There are as many files as there are IP addresses. 400,000 files in one directory is seriously cumbersome to deal with.

The distribution of specific IPs in the input may be significant. My data has them randomly distributed, probably the worst case. If the pattern of usage is that IPs make a localised burst of accesses and then are not seen again, then the files to be flushed each time will be fewer and bigger, therefore more efficient.

We can append 400,000 files (one at a time), but we can't append to compressed files, because most of the context is stored in the processes, and we can't run that many processes. So all the data would need to be plain text for a while, and be compressed separately after the extract. So you are going to need 500GB of temporary disk space for a while.

You are welcome to the code, and any assistance you need to tailor it. However, I can't help feeling the analysis of this type of data must have been carried out before, using a database and appropriate tools, and maybe that should be considered, especially if this is more than a one-off exercise.

Comment: thank you for your time and help. I think your solution will solve my problem, I'll also trying to get access to a better machine. Unfortunately I don't have access to how these data are being stored, so my only alternative is to analyze these logs. By the way, I think you forgot to post the code. :)

Comment: Regrettably, I did not analyse the first code you posted in full. I attacked the problem assuming you wanted every individual IP in a different output file. You were splitting the input into NUM_FILES parts, with IPs divided equally (but randomly) between the outputs. Writing 400,000 files has a serious performance hit. I have done some testing and clean-up. Would you want a solution that made a specific (but parameterised) number of files (e.g. 400 files each with data for 1000 IPs)? I can rework this today, and post code on PasteBin.

Comment: We could also consider an initial pass to find all the IPs, and then make multiple passes to get them in groups. E.g. make 10 groups of IPs, make 10 passes over the input with NUM_FILES=40, and end up with 10x40 files each with 1000 IPs. That would mean you could work with 50GB free space, because you could recompress each group of 40 files between passes. Need to consider relative timings for different approaches.

Comment: Well, my main goal is to be able to split without using swap. If it will create one file per IP or not, it's not important to me. I have almost almost 900GB to use as temp disk space.